# How to use achartengine to draw Multi Y axises

Tags: android

I use achartengine develper an android app ,now i only draw 2 Y axises,but i need 4 Y axises,i searched on Internet and read achartengine API, but dont learn how to draw multi Y axises, who can help me, thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

You can start by downloading the AChartEngine demo. In the demo, there is a "Temperature and sunshine" chart which has multiple Y axis. That is the best place to start learning how to do this. The code can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/MultipleTemperatureChart.java).

Comment: thank you ,i try AchartEngine ,but it dont support 4 Y axises , i used afreechart, it did well

Comment: AChartEngine does support as many Y axis as you need. You just need to figure out how to use it, like any other library.

Comment: I tried ,but dont , it supports two Y axises well ,but I dont find method to and many Y axis,also the document said it can.when I have to used afreechart which dont support well if and too much data ,it will cash too much time.